# It would probably have been X the one variant that

Tags: phrases, emphasis

Let's say that I am being asked which of a series of variants is the one that, in my opinion, prevailed historically.

Can I answer emphatically, expressing an assumption about the past, that way: It would probably have been X the one variant that prevailed at the time.

Thanks.

Comment: If "X" is for an event, then I would say "It is probably X that prevailed at that time." For example: "It is probably WWII that prevailed at that time."

Comment: And what about putting it that way: It would most likely have been X the very one variant that....  (I just want to keep it emphatic)

Comment: To me, the following is simpler and more natural: *It's likely that X prevailed at the time.*

Comment: The use of *variant* in your question is unclear.